# Is there a tidy way to mutate individual cells in a tibble?

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble

How do I change individual cells, preferably using the `%>%`?

For example:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- iris %>% 
  slice(1:5)
```

Produces this:

```
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
```

And if I want to change a cell, I would do this:

```
df[1,1] <- 6
```

Which gives me this:

```
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          6.0         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
```

But is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `purrr::assign_in`:

```
library(tidyverse)

iris %>% 
  slice(1:5) %>% 
  assign_in(list(1, 1), 6)
#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#1          6.0         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
#2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
#5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
```

Comment: One thing that I did notice is that `list(1, 1)` is `column, row`, whereas `[1,1]` is `row, column`.

Comment: Is there a way to use a condition as the row element in the `assign_in` function? E.g. assign if `Sepal.Width < 3.2`?